# Null safe string

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a localzation string which apparently if set to null is causing issues in the view.   So my solution was to string it.

```
_localizer["Controller_Account_ResetPassword_ResetFailed"].ToString();
```

During code review my co-worker reminded me that .ToString() is not null safe.  While its highly unlikely that a localization would be null I guess it could be.  He suggested the following.

```
TempData["Message"] = $"{_localizer["Controller_Account_ResetPassword_ResetFailed"]}";
```

I have two questions.

1. Why is $"{var}" null safe and .ToString() is not.
2. Is there a better way of doing it because his solution seams ugly to me.

Comment: (2) `x + ""` is the most concise way. Of course you could do `?.ToString() ?? ""` as well or custom extension method. Using interpolated string just for that is ugly and should be avoided.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, the reason is that it's basically decompiled as

```
var arg = _localizer["Controller_Account_ResetPassword_ResetFailed"];
string.Format("{0}", arg);
```

and `string.Format` [does a `null` check on its arguments and automatically replaces them with `string.Empty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads).

<s>Second of all, this solution is beautiful and string interpolation is an ingenious tool. You should use it :)</s>

EDIT:

I kinda overlooked the fact here string interpolation is used *solely* to fix the `null` problem. As some have pointed out that is unnecessary and as much as everyone should love string interpolation something like this:

```
_localizer["Controller_Account_ResetPassword_ResetFailed"]?.ToString() ?? "";
```

would be a better choice.

Comment: The only answer that actually answers the question on why interpolation is null safe.

Comment: Dont get me wrong i love interpolation it just seams weird to use it in this manner (a variable by itself). I guess i have only consider it as something to use like string concatenation.  However in this case we arnt actually concatenating anything

Comment: I have edited my post to reflect the fact that string interpolation prooobably **is** overkill in this situation.

Comment: _localizer["Controller_Account_ResetPassword_ResetFailed"]?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;    <--- wonder if that would blow up my view.

Comment: `string.Empty` vs `""` is purely a matter of taste, so.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use a ToStringSafe extension method for these kind of scenarios

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToStringSafe(this object value)
    {
        // return empty string
        if (value == null) {
            return String.Empty;
        }

        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `??` operator to substitute `""` if needed:

```
var something = _localizer["Controller_Account_ResetPassword_ResetFailed"] ?? "";
```

I wouldn't use `$"{value}"` notation here. First of all it probably is unneeded, second it does extra work by calling `string.Format()` which internally creates a `StringBuilder` object.

It also is by no means clear that the only and actual reason for calling `$"{value}"` would be *to deal with a potential null value*, which is 100% clear when you use `??`.

Comment: You will get an error, because var doesn't know what type it is. Add ?.ToString() to the localizer.

Comment: The question starts with `I have a localzation string`, from which I assume that `_localizer` is something that delivers a string (e.g. a Dictionary<string, string>)

Comment: Hmm, I guess you could be right. It seems like OP was using ToString() as a means to handle the null, not because it's not a string.

Answer (score 0):

As it was stated above the string interpolation is null-safe as it's converted internally to the string.Format. However to answer the second question the information of how you're going to handle rare case with null localization is required. The solution suggested by your colleague is good (I'd only recommend to extract the variable instead of inlining for better readability), but you possibly may want to fall back to the non-localized version of the message instead of getting empty string in case of localization absence or handle the situation in any other way. In that case you'll have to do the explicit null verification possibly inside the _localizer type implementation so that it's always guaranteed to return non-null values or fail.